# Redirect loop after installing SecureLogin module

Tags: redirection

I have only just installed the [SecureLogin](http://drupal.org/project/securelogin) module and after enabling it, I cannot access any user pages or forms that have been configured to enable HTTPS.

I only ever get 310 redirect loop errors.

**Edit:** 
I have managed to fix the issue by commenting out the **$base_url** configuration I had set up in *settings.php* . Now the site redirects correctly but still shows some unsecured content (styles and scripts from the header mainly).

Comment: Have you had a look at this [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1246368)?

Comment: Hi, yes I have already looked through that before I posted here. I think I figured the problem though.

Comment: If you are sure this was your problem (and it probably was) then you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fix the issue by commenting out the `$base_url` configuration I had set up in `settings.php`. Now the site redirects correctly but still shows some unsecured content (styles and scripts from the header mainly).